# I am getting error of when try to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I create the API and it is working locally. I can send mail but when i publish the code on server I got below error.
My code also perfect. I try different some way also.

[image: error image]

```
 SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
                SmtpMail.Host = "hostname";
                SmtpMail.Port = 587;
                SmtpMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailid", "password");
                SmtpMail.EnableSsl = false;
                SmtpMail.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 0;
                SmtpMail.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 2000, 2000);
                SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you customized the wrong message. So we need more error information to locate the problem. The tip 2 maybe can help you solve the issue.

Please add `try..catch..` like below to get more detailed messages:

```
        SmtpMail.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 0;
        SmtpMail.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 2000, 2000);
        try
        {
            SmtpMail.Send(mail);

            return Ok("send successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok("send failed, error msg: " + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
```

**Tips**

1. When I set `SmtpMail.EnableSsl = false;`  and I get the error message:

   send failed, error msg: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)

   So my suggestion is set `SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;`
2. If your host is `smtp.gmail.com`, then you [should use `Application-specific passwords`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#app-passwords).

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: i try your way also 
still same issue 
it is working on local but some how on server only not working.
Failure sending mail.

Comment: @Tarun43 Have you added try...catch... ? I need more details. gmail ? Outlook ?

Answer (score 0):

The "failure sending email" error in most scenarios is pointing to "time out" error, you're using 587 port, and in most configs, this port is using TLS so you need to enable your SSL

```
SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
```

but I offer you to use try catch for catching your errors, and log them if you want, but with try catch the errors appear in the true way

for more, 25 and 2525 ports don't use secure connection (I offer you to avoid them for your security if you can)

but 587 and 465 ports use secure connection